# Hiding google map v3 markers. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: google-maps, toggle, google-maps-markers

I am trying to hide a selected category of google map markers when an external javascript function hidetype() is called. To no avail.

I took the general concept from: http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_categories.html

Below is the code that extracts my marker info from mysql derived XML. I have the markers grouped by type.

```
      downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml2_snow.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "Some infoBubble HTML";
      var Gtip = "<b>" + name + "</b>";
      var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
      var hover = icon.hover;
      var hoverout = icon.icon;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon,
        shadow: icon.shadow,
      });
      marker.mytype = type;
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html, Gtip, hover, hoverout);
    }
  });
}

function hidetype(category) {
  alert(category);
    for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
      if (markers[i].mytype == category) {
        markers[i].setVisible(false);
      }
    }
  }
```

An example of how I'd externally try to remove markers is:

```
<img onclick="hidetype('1')" src=...>
```

This currently spits out an alert with the passed type variable but doesn't remove the markers. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Resolved. I needed to create a new array variable (gmarkers in example) that was pushed with every new marker creation. Then, in the hidetype function, 'markers' needed to get changed to 'gmarkers'